# DLookup Error within an Access 2007 Form

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have built a form "Main" based on a table "APL 8-14-2014" in Access 2007. The client has requested additional data within the same form "Main" not originally included in the original table "APL 8-14-2014".

I built a query "OverallRankingQry" combining  "Overall_Ranking" with the Primary Key "Project ID" originally included in the "APL 8-14-2014" Table.

How do I pull this query into my expression builder in my form? I have attempted to write a dlookup with only the #NAME? error result. I think I am not properly defining that current open Form's "ID" is equal to the "Project ID" within the query, but this is just a guess.

Desired Field = Overall_Ranking
From Query = OverallRankingQry
Based on Criteria = "ID" in open Form will be equal to "Project ID" field within OverallRankingQry

`=DLookUp([Overall_Ranking],[OverallRankingQry],"[ID]=[Form]![MAIN]")`

Comment: I have edited the code to =DLookUp("[Overall_Ranking]","[OverallRankingQry]","[Project ID]=" & [Forms]![Main]![Project ID])

I'd still like to know which part fixed it? The quotations? (even though what I am calling are numbers?)

I did change the forms text box to "Project ID" from "ID" because I was getting confused which portion of my criteria referred to my open form and which referred to my query fields.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are wanting to use the query builder for the form and create the join between your table and your new query. Hit the ellipses (...) and build the Record Source like you built the query, only include the original table and the new query you've written with a join between them on the ID.